# python regex exclude text containing word

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to filter texts using regex in python. The goal is:
Check if the ***text has the word W not preceded by X*** or not followed by Y.
so lets say:

W=**"day"**, X=**"awful"**, Y=**"light"**

```
"what a beautiful day it is" => should pass
"nice day"          => should pass    
"awful day"         => should fail
"such an awful day" => should fail
"the day light"     => should fail
"awful day light"   => should fail
"day light"         => should fail
```

I've tried several things like:

```
r".*\b(?!awful\b)day\b.*"
r"\W*\b(?!awful\b)day\b.*"  => to be able to include \n \r since '.' doesnt

r".*\b(day)\b(?!light\b).*"
r"\W*\b(day)\b(?!light\b)\W*"  => to be able to include \n \r since '.' doesnt
```

So complete example would be, (should fail)

```
if (re.search(r".*\b(?!awful\b)day\b.*", "such an awful day", re.UNICODE):
    print "Found awful day! no good!"
```

Still wondering how to do that!
any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to use regex? What if the string is just `daylight`? How about `today`? How about `this day is awful`?

Comment: i get your point, but is targeted only at some particular words. Like people names, etc. Maybe i didnt pick the best words for the example.
I thought regex would be cool, but im starting to think it might be better to do it in a couple more lines of code without regex.

Comment: Regex might be more power than you need. Split on whitespace, then do your own inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 # ^(?s)((?!X).)*W((?!Y).)*$

 ^ 
 (?s)
 (
      (?! X )
      . 
 )*
 W 
 (
      (?! Y )
      . 
 )*
 $
```

or, with word boundries

```
 # ^(?s)((?!\bX\b).)*\bW\b((?!\bY\b).)*$

 ^ 
 (?s)
 (
      (?! \b X \b )
      . 
 )*
 \b W \b 
 (
      (?! \b Y \b )
      . 
 )*
 $
```

**edit** - It was unclear if you meant X<->W<->Y was separated by whitespace
or any number of characters. This expanded, commented example shows both ways.
Good luck!
Note - the `(?add-remove)` construct is a modifier group. Typically its a way to
embed options like s (Dot-All), i(Ignore case), etc.., within the regex.
Where `(?s)` means add Dot-All modifier, and `(?si)` is the same but with ignore case as well.

```
 #  ^(?s)(?!.*(?:\bX\b\s+\bW\b|\bW\b\s+\bY\b))(?:.*\b(W)\b.*|.*)$

 # This regex validates W is not preceded by X
 # nor followed by Y.
 # It also optionally finds W.
 # Only fails if its invalid.
 # If passed, can check if W present by
 # examining capture group 1.

 ^                         # Beginning of string
 (?s)                      # Modifier group, with s = DOT_ALL
 (?!                       # Negative looahead assertion
      .*                        # 0 or more any character (dot-all is set, so we match newlines too)
      (?:
           \b X \b \s+ \b W \b       # Trying to match X, 1 or more whitespaces, then W
        |  \b W \b \s+ \b Y \b       # Or, Trying to match W, 1 or more whitespaces, then Y

           # Substitute this to find any interval between X<->W<->Y
           #    \b X \b .* \b W \b       <- Trying to match X, 0 or more any char, then W
           # |  \b W \b .* \b Y \b       <- Or, Trying to match W, 0 or more any char, then Y
      )
 )

 # Still at start of line. 
 # If here, we didn't find any X<->W, nor W<->Y.
 # Opotioinally finds W in group 1.
 (?:
      .* \b 
      ( W )                     # (1), W
      \b .* 
   |  
      .* 
 )
 $                         # End of string
```

Comment: wow, thanks, that seems to be working. Im gonna make work tests, but so far it worked!

Comment: what does '?s' mean? im gooling but couldnt find it yet.

Comment: @sebastian - Sorry, didn't see this till now. `(?s)` is the Dot-All embedded modifier. See my latest edit. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Try:

```
(?<!\bawful\b )\bday\b(?!\s+\blight\b)
```

Demo:

```
st='''\
"what a beautiful day it is" => should pass
"nice day"          => should pass    
"awful day"         => should fail
"such an awful day" => should fail
"the day light"     => should fail
"awful day light"   => should fail
"day light"         => should fail'''

W, X, Y = 'day', 'awful', 'light'
pat=r'(?<!\b{}\b )\b{}\b(?!\s+\b{}\b)'.format(X, W, Y)

import re

for line in st.splitlines():
    m=re.search(pat, line)
    if m:
        print line
```

Comment: Seems to match `awful   day`, that has extra whitespace between them. Don't know if it can be resolved with that lookbehind assertion there.